# iOS Firebase Pod - framework not found FirebaseCore error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate `Firebase` Cloud Messaging in iOS application. Added `Firebase` Core and `Firebase` Messaging pods and made all the required setup.

Below are the pods used.

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

While doing clean and build, the application build fails with error:

```
"ld: framework not found FirebaseCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to be sure are you opening workspace or xcode project?

Comment: any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

use "command + B" if it doesn't work

Hold your application on simulator a second and delete it. then run the Xcode again.